# Why copy constructor not getting called in this case

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, most-vexing-parse

Say, I have a class A

Now when I am doing

```
A a(A());
```

what exactly happens?

Comment: I would imagine that would be optimized out if it's not being called.

Comment: @chris I'm not so sure. The return value optimization (RVO) is permitted, but what about copies within a single function?

Comment: @chris...I know of the copy constructor elison concept for the case A a = A(), in this case the default constructor gets called.But in above case neither default nor copy constructor is getting called

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @Bo Persson it ain't a duplicate. `A a(())` and `A a(A())` are different things.

Comment: @Radek - Read the question, it is all there! "Why doesn't `A a(B())` work?" is a perfect duplicate for "Why doesn't `A a(A())` work?".

Comment: @BoPersson: Read the linked question - it's asking why the invalid code `A a(())` (with only one `A`) doesn't compile, and just mentions the "Most Vexing Parse" to set the scene. It's not a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite appearances, `A a(A());` is not an object definition. Instead, it declares a function called `a` that returns an `A` and takes a pointer to a function taking nothing and returning an `A`.

If you want an object definition, you have to add another pair of parenthesis:

```
A a((A()));
```

Comment: Use `A a{A{}}` in C++11 to call the copy ctor if you don't want an extra set of parenthesis.

Comment: @FredOverflow Can you explain in little detail :)

Comment: @FredOverflow....can you please give an example how to use this function declaration.

Comment: Since it's only a *declaration*, not a *definition*, you will get a linker error if you try to call the function. Don't get too hung up on this, just add the extra pair of parenthesis and get on with your code ;)

Answer (score 8):

If written correctly - `A a((A()))` - the compiler creates the temporary directly in the constructor context to prevent an extra copy. It's called **copy elision**. Look this up, along with RVO and NRVO.

From your comment:

```
A a = A();
```

this is **exactly** equivalent to

```
A a((A())); // note extra pair of parenthesis
```

As @Naveen correctly pointed out, `A a(A());` is subject to most vexing parse, so you need an extra set of paranthesis there to actually create an object.

Comment: is it not an example for the most vexing C++ parse ? I tried with this code: http://ideone.com/ZVXoT

Comment: @Naveen yes, extra set of paranthesis there.